# recursively delete subdirectories and files

Tags: command-line, rm

I have the following files and directories configuration:

```
-Parent_dir
    |-delme_dir
    |-delme_file
    |-aFile
    |-sub_dir
        |-delme_dir
        |-delme_file
        |-aFile
        |-sub_dir
            |-delme_dir
            |-delme_file
            |-aFile
    |-sub_dir2
        |-delme_dir
        |-delme_file
        |-aFile
```

Is there a command that I can use from the **Parent_dir** to recursively remove all the **delme_dir directories** and the **delme_file files** ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In single command you could do this:

```
find . \( -type d -name "delme_dir" -o -type f -name "delme_file" \) -delete
```

If there is no other directories or files match with pattern `delme_*`, you can do in short.

```
find . -name "delme_*" -delete
```

Answer (score 4):

You can combine `find`, `xargs` and `rm`:

```
find . -type f -a -name delme_files -print0 | xargs -0 rm
```

and

```
find . -type d -a -name delme_dir -print0 | xargs -0 rmdir
```

(when you are in the `Parent_dir` directory)

There is probably a way to combine  the two `find` into only one but I find it clearer like that anyway.

The `find` commands will find the directories/files named per your example, and you pipe the results to `xargs` that will execute `rm` (remove) / `rmdir` (remove directory) on each of the file find "upstream", that is from the `file` command.

If the directories are not empty, replace `rmdir` by `rm -Rf` but this will remove recursively all files in the directories found by the `find` command.

The combo `-print0` / `-0` will make sure that all files/directories will be dealt correctly, even those having spaces in their names (maybe not needed here but better to use in generic cases).

Make  sure to test things before on non important data and always have backups.

Comment: `-a` is not necessary

Comment: @αғsнιη yes -a is not necessary, but not a problem either. better to show that you can do combination of logic statements

Answer (score 2):

```
shopt -s globstar
echo **/*delme* | xargs rm
```

Comment: why not "rm **/*delme*"? Or is it because builtin echo does not have an argument limit?

Comment: I think that every expantion is limited by certain system limits. However using of xargs may be a solution.